# Why has the sponge construction's generic collision finding attack a complexity of O(min(2^(-n/2) , 2^(-c/2)))?

Tags: collision-resistance, sha-3, keccak, sponge

I'm trying to learn about sponge function for creating hash functions and generic attacks on it.

I'm looking for the collision finding attack scenario which leads to $O(\min(2^{-n/2} , 2^{-c/2}))$ time complexity, where $n$ is the sponge output length(hash output length) and $c$ is the capacity length of sponge state.

I know that $2^{-n/2}$ comes from a traditional birthday attack on the output, but what is the attack scenario for $2^{-c/2}$ complexity?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Denote the internal sponge state by
$$
S = R\mathbin\|C,
$$
where $C$ has size $c$ — capacity.

Every iteration a message block of length $|R|$ is xored into $R$ and then the permutation $P$ is applied. Therefore, if we obtain a collision in $C$ (which can be obtained in $2^{c/2}$ steps with the basic [birthday attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack)), we could cancel any difference in $R$ by injecting an appropriate pair of messages.

So, if $(M_1,M_2)$ yields a zero difference in $C$ and difference $\Delta R$ in $R$,
the pair
$$
(M_1\mathbin\|X,M_2\mathbin\|(X\oplus \Delta R)) 
$$
is a collision pair for the full function $F$ for any $X$.